# Bootstrap table with nested components in angular4

Tags: angular

I'm the begginer with angular4, and i  am trying to build bootstrap table with nested components, the child component is display in single row.
But table is not display correctly.please see the below image

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsuNf.png)

parent component

```
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Done</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <app-child *ngFor="let todo of this.todos " [todo]="todo" (eventRemove)="remove(todo)"></app-child>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<div>
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit(f.value)">
    <label for="title"></label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" [(ngModel)]="this.todo.title">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>



import { Todo } from '../todo';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public todos: Todo[] = [];
  public todo: Todo = { title: "", done: false };
  formSubmit(value) {
    var todo = { title: value.title, done: false };
    this.todos.push(todo);
  }
  constructor() {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todos.push({ title: "clean your room", done: false });
    this.todos.push({ title: "clean your desk", done: true });

  }
  remove(t) {
    let index = this.todos.indexOf(t);
    this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("removed", t);
  }

}
```

Child component

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {{todo.title}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="todo.done">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="onRemove(todo)">Remove</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

import { Todo } from '../todo';
import { Component, Input,Output, OnInit ,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input()
      todo: Todo;
      @Output()
      eventRemove = new EventEmitter<Todo>();
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
      onRemove(data) {

        this.eventRemove.emit(data);
      }
    }
```

Comment: not make a child, < tbody>< tr>
    < td  *ngFor="let todo of this.todos >
        {{todo.title}}
    < /td>...< /tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a child component to show the table, just call this child **once**, and put the ngFor loop **inside that child**, passing the 'this.todos' variable.

But if you are showing the table only in one place, using a child possibly doesn't make much sense, you could just loop 'this.todos' in the `<tbody>` and that's it.